# I run launchd and I get an error that says "invalid property list"

Tags: launchd, python

When I run launchctl to load/start the plist with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.web_blocker</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Python 3.6</string>
        <string>/Users/michaelcunningham/Desktop/website_blocker.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>60</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I get the error "invalid property list". How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: i added <true/> but it still comes back with the same error

Comment: I copied **your** plist, added the <true/> line, saved it to my LaunchAgents folder and loaded the plist with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.web_blocker.plist` without an error message - even though I neither have a folder /Applications/Python 3.6 nor a user michaelcunningham or a website_blocker.py!

Comment: maybe it has to do with LaunchAgents folder? i have a couple.  how can i ensure it goes into the correct folder?  i still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

Your plist is missing at least the line `<true/>` (or `<false/>`) after the line `<key>RunAtLoad</key>`.

The line `<string>/Applications/Python 3.6</string>` is useless because this is just a folder but no app/binary. Your Python script may work nevertheless, provided the shebang is set properly.